# FLASH AS3 EXTERNAL CLASS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, external

I have a problem regarding as3.

I have done a flash application that include an external class in the same folder with the swf. Now the problem is, when I edit the information on the external class (using notepad++), the swf doesn't change. Its like the external class has been hard coded into the application itself.

Do I have to make some changes on the publish setting?

Thanks guys for your time. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to re-compile your project into the swf. (at least I did when I was writing AS3 programs)

you can't just expect the swf to see your changes sitting there and re-compile itself(although it would be awesome if it did).

just re-build your flash application like you built it the first time.

Comment: hello Sam (can I call you Sam?). Thanks for your reply. So if I have to re-compile every time I make changes on the external as3, so what's the point of having the script externally? Or the external script serve another function? thanks mate

Comment: There can be a couple gains for having your code in external AS files, one of which is that you can separate your code by logic into different files to ease maintenance/updates. Another might be you could have multiple people working on different parts of the code at the same time (assuming they are touching different areas of the code since they are separate files) or a developer editing an fla (graphical assets) and another working on the code. Still more, since AS files are "plain text", they can be easier to handle (smaller file size, comparing and merging, etc). And so on.

Comment: nice one...thanks mitim for your explanation..appreciate it..so now I have to think a solution for my problem. Thanks guys for your explanation...cheers!